# this._state is undefined in store.js. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm new here and I'm working on a social media app for a course, and I'm encountering several issues with Redux and state management. Initially, I fixed a `props.dispatch is not a function` error by using `connect` in MyPosts.jsx and Provider in index.js.

However, I'm now facing the error `"this._state is undefined"` in store.js when trying to access `this._state`, and the console also shows an error related to `props.dispatch(action)` in MyPosts.jsx.

Here's the code:

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';




import store from './redux/store'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

console.log('store in index.js:' + store.getState())
console.log(store)


let rerenderEntireTree = (state) =\> {
  root.render(
      \<BrowserRouter\>
        \<Provider store={store}\>
          \<App state={store.\_state} dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)}/\>
        \</Provider\>
      \</BrowserRouter\>, document.getElementById('root')
  )
}

rerenderEntireTree(store.\_state)
store.subscribe(rerenderEntireTree)



reportWebVitals();
```

**MyPosts.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import cls from './MyPosts.module.css';
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { addPostActionCreator, updateNewPostTextActionCreator } from "../../../redux/store";


const MyPosts = (props) =\> {


    let newPostElement = useRef();

    let addPost = () =\> {
        let text = newPostElement.current.value;
        let action = addPostActionCreator(text);
        props.dispatch(action);
    };

    let onPostChange = () =\> {
        let text = newPostElement.current.value;

        let action = updateNewPostTextActionCreator(text);
        props.dispatch(action);
    }

    return (
        \<div className={cls.postsComponent}\>
            \<h4\>My posts\</h4\>

            \<textarea onChange={onPostChange} className={cls.textarea} ref={newPostElement} value={props.newPostText}/\>
            \<input type="button" onClick={addPost} className={cls.button} value="Send"/\>

            \<div className={cls.posts}\>
                \<Post posts={props.posts} /\>
            \</div\>
        \</div\>
    );
};


export default connect(null)(MyPosts);
```

**store.js:**

```
let i = 900


let store = {
  \_state: {
    newPostText: '',
    contacts: \[
        {
          name: "Paul",
            //removed url img
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Bob",
            //removed url img
          id: 2
        },
        {
          name: "Serena",
            //removed url img
          id: 3
        },
        {
          name: "Steve",
            //removed url img
          id: 4
        },
        {
          name: "Michael",
            //removed url img
          id: 5
        },
        {
          name: "Max",
            //removed url img
          id: 6
        },
        {
          name: "Billy",
            //removed url img
          id: 7
        },
        {
          name: "Tom",
            //removed url img
          id: 8
        },
        {
          name: "George",
            //removed url img
          id: 9
        },
        {
          name: "John",
            //removed url img
          id: 10
        },
        {
          name: "Mike",
            //removed url img
          id: 11
        },
        {
          name: "David",
            //removed url img
          id: 12
        },
        {
          name: "Luke",
            //removed url img
          id: 13
        },
        {
          name: "Liam",
            //removed url img
          id: 14
        },
        {
          name: "Emma",
            //removed url img
          id: 15
        },
        {
          name: "Olivia",
            //removed url img
          id: 16
        },
        {
          name: "Noah",
            //removed url img
          id: 17
        },
        {
          name: "Emma",
            //removed url img
          id: 18
        },
        {
          name: "Olivia",
            //removed url img
          id: 19
        },
        {
          name: "Noah",
            //removed url img
          id: 20
        },
        {
          name: "Emma",
            //removed url img
          id: 21
        },
        {
          name: "Olivia",
            //removed url img
          id: 22
        },
        {
          name: "Noah",
            //removed url img
          id: 23
        }
      \],

      posts: \[
        {
            //removed url img
            content: "Hey how r y'all doin'?",
            likes: 12,
            dislikes: 5
        },
        {
            //removed url img
            content: 'whasup',
            likes: 41,
            dislikes: 2
        },
        {
            //removed url img
            content: 'Eh? What? ',
            likes: 84,
            dislikes: 15
        },
      \],

      messages: \[
        {
            content: "Hello",
            seenByMe: true,
            seenByOther: false,
            isSender: true,
            time: "18:00"
        },
        {
            content: "How are you?",
            seenByMe: false,
            seenByOther: true,
            isSender: false,
            time: "18:10"
        },
        {
            content: "I'm good, thanks!",
            seenByMe: true,
            seenByOther: true,
            isSender: true,
            time: "18:12"
        },
        {
            content: "Did you watch the game last night?",
            seenByMe: true,
            seenByOther: false,
            isSender: false,
            time: "18:15"
        },
        {
            content: "No, I missed it. Who won?",
            seenByMe: false,
            seenByOther: true,
            isSender: true,
            time: "18:16"
        },
        {
            content: "The home team won. It was an exciting match!",
            seenByMe: false,
            seenByOther: false,
            isSender: false,
            time: "18:17"
        },
        {
            content: "That's great! I'll catch the highlights later.",
            seenByMe: true,
            seenByOther: false,
            isSender: true,
            time: "18:20"
        }
      \]
  },



  getState(){
    return this.\_state
  },

  rerenderEntireTree() {
    this.\_state = {
      ...this.\_state
    }

    console.log('State changed')
  },

  \_callSubscriber(){
    this.\_rerenderEntireTree(this.\_state)
  },



  subscribe(observer) {
    this.\_rerenderEntireTree = observer
  },

  dispatch(action) {
    if (action.type === 'ADD-POST') {
      let newPost = { 
        content: this.\_state.newPostText,
        likes: 0,
        dislikes: 0
      };

      this.\_state.posts.push(newPost);
      this.\_state.newPostText = '';
      this.\_callSubscriber(this.\_state);

      i++;
    } else if (action.type === 'UPDATE-NEW-POST-TEXT') {
      this.\_state.newPostText = action.newText;
      this.\_callSubscriber(this.\_state);
    }
  }
  
  

}

let addPostActionCreator = () =\> {
  return {
      type: 'ADD-POST'
  }
}
let updateNewPostTextActionCreator = (text) =\> {
  return {
      type: 'UPDATE-NEW-POST-TEXT',
      newText: text
  }
}



export {addPostActionCreator, updateNewPostTextActionCreator}

export default store
window.store = store
```

edit: I added comments where i said i removed img so that stackoverflow doesn't see it as spam

I would really appreciate any help in fixing these issues. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've defined store as a local variable inside store.js
this._state won't work in this case. I didn't completely understand your style of implementing store here but to access the '_state' property, try 'store._state' instead of 'this._state'

Comment: Yes it worked! Tysm!